# how to get tooltip text which is generated dynamic

Tags: tooltip, selenium-webdriver, dhtml, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

```html
<tbody>
 <tr class="" style="height:65px;">
 <tr class="" style="height:65px;">
  <td class="dhx_matrix_scell" style="width:99px; height:64px;">Ashmita </td>
  <td>
   <div class="dhx_matrix_line" style="width:1181px; height:65px; position:relative;">
    <div class="dhx_marked_timespan dhx_matrix_now_time" style="height: 64px; left: 105px; width: 1px; top: 0px;"></div>
    <div class="dhx_marked_timespan gray_section" style="height: 64px; left: 588px; width: 591px; top: 0px;"></div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_event_line Booked" style="position:absolute; top:2px; height: 17px; left:99px; width:28px;" event_id="1374736442513">
    <table class="" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:1181px; height:65px;">
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="" style="height:65px;">
 <tr class="" style="height:65px;">
 <tr class="" style="height:65px;">
 <tr class="" style="height:65px;">
</tbody>
```

In the above code when I hover the mouse on the element  `<div class="dhx_cal_event_line Booked" style="position:absolute; top:2px; height: 17px; left:99px; width:28px;" event_id="1374736442513">`, I get a tooltip tipsy which is generate dynamically; I can't catch it using firepath. I have tried the action class like

```java
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='scheduler']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div[4]"));
action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
System.out.println("the tool tip text is"+element.getText());
action.moveToElement(element).release().build().perform();
```

but i get null as element text.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the tooltip? I'm guessing that it's not a small basic tooltip, but a larger html-enabled panel of some kind?

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='scheduler']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div[4]"));
    action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
```

Put a `String source = driver.getPageSource();` and then save that source somewhere (or print it to console)

Take a look at the page source, to see what element has the tooltip text in it, and then you can write a selector for it.

Comment: the path which i mentioned ".//*[@id='scheduler']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div[4]" is not valid if one more element presents in the table row and the event_id="1374736442513" is generated by dhtml-calendar it is dynamic one. now how to fetch the element ?

Comment: Could you please post the HTML source (anything within the element with the scheduler ID)